# If and only if condition for UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

This is a question in abstract algebra.

Question : Let $D$ : integral domain. Show that $D$ is a UFD if and only is every nonzero element is a product of finitely many prime elements.

But I think this question is wrong. If the condition on right has 'uniquely', it would be right.

(But it is ACTUALLY the definition of UFD...)

Is this question wrong? Or something I misunderstood...?

Comment: You seem to be confusing prime elements (which generate a prime ideal) and irreducible elements.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as stated, is correct.

As has been mentioned in the comments, you seem to be confusing [primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) with [irreducibles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element). This is an extremely common mistake, but one which you should be cognizant of!

As for the problem itself, here's a hint:

Can you show that if an element of an integral domain admits a *prime* factorization, then this factorization must be unique (up to order and units, of course)?

Once you have this, since every element admits a prime factorization in our ring of interest, we see that every element admits a *unique* prime factorization. So we have UFD-ness.

---

There are lots of examples of non-UFDs where every element admits a (non-unique!) factorization into *irreducibles*. Every noetherian ring has this property, for instance. Factorization into primes is a stronger condition, though (as this question shows).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Ah, so simply speaking, if finitely many prime factorization is possible, it is unique. And since every prime element is irreducible in an integral domain, it is the definition of UFD. Right?

Comment: You've got it ^_^